# How to flatten nested JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Let's say I am dealing with JSON like this:

http://hndroidapi.appspot.com/nestedcomments/format/json/id/4620423?appid=hntoolbar&callback=

Which can be infinitely nested.  I want to extract all of the comment information in a "flattened" format, just a list of usernames and the contents of their comment without worrying about the "level" of the comment.  How would I do something like that using Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/ -- flattens objects, give it a try and post your attempt if you get stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use recursion:

```
var getall = function(comments,out) {
    var out = out || {};
    var cuser = undefined;
    var comment;
    for (var key in comments) {
        if (key == 'username') {
            cuser = comments[key];
            continue;
        }
        if (key == 'comment') {
            comment = comments[key];
            continue;
        }
        var mytype = typeof(comments[key]);
        if (mytype == 'object'
        || mytype == 'array') {
            out=getall(comments[key],out);
        };
    }
    if (cuser !== undefined) {
        if (out[cuser] === undefined) {
            out[cuser] = [];
        }

       out[cuser].push(comment);
    }
    return (out);
}
b=getall(a);
console.log(b);​
```

a here - parsed JSON, b - result;

b structure is

`{user1: [comment,comment,comment],user2: [] ...}`

http://jsfiddle.net/NkTst/1/

check http://jsfiddle.net/NkTst/2/ if you still need extended info on comments

Comment: Used a modified version of your approach, thanks!  I have no idea why I didn't think to use recursion, I was being lazy I guess.

Comment: Or, perhaps, not lazy enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did when I had to do that in python:
(It is not complete, I will try and do it in javascript later for practive though.)
I posted that because the idea of recursion is much clearer in this one.

```
#Builds the names and makes a nested list with {"table.hierarchy.id":value} pairs:
def undic(dic,levs=0,tmp=""):
    if(isinstance(dic,dict)):
        return([undic(dic[d],levs=levs+1,tmp=tmp+d+".") for d in dic.keys()])
    else:
        return {tmp : dic}

#Flattens the list to something we can easilly work with:
def flat_content(dic):
    ll=undic(dic)
    if(isinstance(ll[0],dict)):
        return(ll)
    return(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,ll))
```

Then find the unique column names and keep the row names from the zero'th level of hierarchy, make some utility functions to handle missing keys etc (I did that with .update({"missingKey":""}) and you have a nice little json to table converter (easily cast to CSV)!

the json from your question is not visible though.